# Closed form expression for parallel transport / Bishop Frame along a cubic Bezier curve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, closed-form, bezier-curve

I would like to define a rotation minimizing frame (also known as a Bishop Frame) for a curve. This should be equivalent to parallel transporting *a* unit normal vector along the curve and then building a frame with the unit tangent vector. I've read of approximate methods for doing this (e.g., "Computation of rotation minimizing frames" [Wang et al. 2008]).

I'm wondering if it's known how to express the Bishop Frame in *closed form*, if we specifically consider a [cubic Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves) in 3D:

$$
\mathbf{x}(s) = (1-s)^3 \mathbf{p}_0 + 3(1-s)^2s \mathbf{p}_1 + 3(1-s)s^2 \mathbf{p}_2 + s^3\mathbf{p}_3,
$$
where the control points $\mathbf{p}_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are constants?

(Or whether it's known that a closed form somehow cannot exist?)

If not, I'm hoping for some pointers on how to derive this (I am happy to use symbolic math software, too).

So far, I've had some luck with Maple and *quadratic* Bezier curves by hardcoding a mapping of the curve to the $xy$ plane and fixing $\mathbf{p}_0$ at the origin and $\mathbf{p}_1$ at $(1,0,0)$, taking advantage of similarity invariance of parallel transport. Then I tell Maple to solve the ODE:

$$\mathbf{f}(0) = \mathbf{f}_0, \mathbf{f}'(s) = (\mathbf{t}(s) \times \mathbf{t}'(s)) \times \mathbf{f}(s),$$ 
where $\mathbf{t}(s) = \mathbf{x}'(s)/\|\mathbf{x}'(s)\|$ is the unit tangent of my cubic Bézier curve. Maple's crunching away at the cubic version, but so far nothing.

Is this the best/easiest ODE to be using for parallel transport? Is there some more convenient expression that would reveal a closed form expression?

Comment: Parallel transport suggests that you're thinking of some underlying geometric structure (a metric or a connection). Can you specify?

Comment: I guess arc-length, although I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Another name for what I'm trying to build is the "Bishop Frame" (see, e.g., "There is more than one way to Frame a Curve" [Bishop 1975]).

Comment: Yes, I am quite familiar with the Bishop frame. You should make that explicit in your question. (The relevant connection is the Riemannian connection on the normal bundle of the curve.) Question: I've never played with the differential geometry of Bezier curves; how badly do they fail to have Frenet frames?

Comment: Update: I picked relatively simple points $p_i$ and Mathematica will calculate the Frenet frame explicitly for me. What's more, the torsion has an elementary integral. This means that we can write down the Bishop frame in closed form, as the angle you rotate from the principal normal is given by integrating the torsion. I'm sure that's in Bishop's paper, but if not, see Exercise 11 on p. 33 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Frenet frame should fail only at zero curvature which (for cubic Bezier curves) is either the entire curve (easy degenerate case) or at isolated point(s). Maple gives reasonable expressions for the tangent and curvature normal. But, I'm having trouble with the torsion integral. I'm guessing I need to give it some assumptions to avoid degeneracies...